# How to solve this formatting date string:

Tags: c#

I am presently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017(version 15.5.7). If I  tried to copy this dateTime code directly from books or websites or me coding it .. for example:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2017,7,4,8,15,30);
Console.Write("Set Date and time: {0:f}",dt);
```

Expected output:

```
Set Date and time:Tuesday, July 4, 2017 8:15 AM
```

Actual output:

```
Set Date and time: July 4, 2017 8:15 AM
```

It does not print out the day, in this case Tuesday

Help

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks lie it's depends from your Windows regional Culture (probably it has been changed from default). You can explicity define outout format:

```
Write("Set date and time: {0:dddd MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt}", dt)
```

Comment: Thanks guys; I am so appreciative, I will try out those answers. However, I suspect it has to do with windows regional culture or  this updated version of Visual Studio 2017......

Comment: Hurray, I just sorted it out !! It was indeed my Windows Regional setting, I have adjusted it to : short date: dd/MM/yyyy and Long date: dddd, dd MMMM yyyy .That should have been checked first.. Thanks Sergey Shulik and D-Shih for your contributions !!!

Comment: Great =) please Mark answer as correct to let know other developers that problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ToString` set your date format.

- `dddd` name of weekday.
- `MMMM` name of month.

like this.

```
string result = "Set Date and time: " + dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:ss tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MMMM_Specifier)

**Result**

```
Set Date and time: Tuesday, July ,4 2017 08:30 AM
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZeopAK)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.ToLongDateString()` but it will dependent your windows date format

Or use `.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")` for custom date format